# Trigger for a variable

Tags: java, mouse

Is there some way to implement a "trigger" for a variable?
In order to exmplain the question, consider a snippet:

I have an application sending data from client to server. I would like to send mouse x/y but only if the value is changed (different as previously).

```
    while(!socket.isClosed()) {

        try {

            MouseKeyboardPacket p = new MouseKeyboardPacket();

            Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

            //Here i would like to wait for the point.x or point.y to be different than previously

            p.setX(point.x);
            p.setY(point.y);

            oos.writeObject(p);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is it possible?

I do know I can do it with `while loop` and `sleep` but it is CPU consuming and has to have a delay which is not what i would like.

I do not use any swing/awt classes with the exception of MouseInfo so no addMouseMotionListener possible...

Comment: Keep track of the previous value and only call the methods when the new value is different?

Comment: @KevinWorkman, i have added a while loop about which i have forgotten